# How to omit an object if one of the fields in object is resolved as null by fieldResolver

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

The products resolver and field resolver of products provides the final-output (given below). But is there a way to omit the objects from final-ouput whose productData is null.

```
@Resolver((of) => Products)
export class ProductsResolver {

  @Query((returns) => [Products], {
    name: 'products',
  })
  getProducts() {
    returns products // returns object [{id: 1, id: 2}]
  }
}
```

```
@Resolver((of) => Products)
export class ProductResolver implements ResolverInterface<Products> {
  @FieldResolver((returns) => ProductType, {
    nullable: false,
    name: 'productData',
  })
  async productData() {
    return object //first time it returns a proper object. 
                  // second time it returns null

  }
}
```

```
@ObjectType()
export default class Products {
  @Field()
  id: string;
  @Field((type) => ProductType, { nullable: true })
  productData: ProductType;
  @Field((type) => Float, { nullable: true })
}
```

final-output

```
  "data": {
    "Products": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "productData": { // inner object }
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "productData": null
      }
    ]
  }
```

desired-output

```
  "data": {
    "Products": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "productData": { // inner object }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite follow what do you want to achieve... what is `ProductDataType` and why you `return [{},null] `?

Comment: sorry for that. 
against each product, the fieldResolver for productData resolves an `object || null`.
And i get the final-output (as mentioned in the question). 
But i want the desired-output (as mentioned in the question) which is I just want to remove the products whose productData is null from final output